# How to access scope in a nested directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a nested directive, where from the nested directive i am trying to pass a function to my controller.... the function is not being triggered.

This is my main directive html

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading" ng-click="collapse()">{{user.name}}</div>
  <div class="panel-body" ng-hide="collapsed">
    <address></address>
    <div>
      <h4>Friends:</h4>
      <div ng-repeat="friend in user.friends">
        {{friend}}
        <remove-friend method="removeFri(friend)"></remove-friend>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="!!user.rank">
        {{user.rank}}
      </div>
      <button ng-show="!user.rank"  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="knightme(user)">Click Me</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above directive i have a `remove-friend` directive which has a property named method and function referencing my controller function `removeFri()`

In my directive i am referencing it like this...

```
 .directive("removeFriend", function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: "removeFriend.html",
        scope : {
          method: "&"
        },
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.remove = function(){
            $scope.method();
          };
        }
      };
  });
```

$scope.method() is never called, trying to put an alert($scope.method()) returns me undefined. Below is a plunker on clicking the x(remove icon), i need to remove the particular item.

https://plnkr.co/edit/d5fStmjspGm5AMmCK9Rx?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `userInfoCard` directive also has an isolated scope, and since you didn't pass it the function from the controller, it was undefined. You need to add it to the scope with `=` binding (since you don't know the parameter yet, and then it will work:

HTML:

```
<user-info-card user="user" collapse="true" remove-fri="removeFri"></user-info-card>
```

Directive:

```
scope: {
    user: '=',
    removeFri: '=',
    initiallyCollapsed: '@collapse'
},
```

[Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/IicYlQlj1DmmgFw0xCAP?p=preview)